# How to update data in real-time

Tags: spring-boot, message-queue, connection-pooling

I have a small stock-market application with Spring boot and if any product updated I want to serve an updated product to the clients in realtime

does it make sense to use message queues like RabbitMQ and Sse(Server Sent Events) for this, or is there a more sensible solution?

Comment: MQ or maybe Websockets? But since its broadcast 1 to many, MQ is the way to go imo.

Comment: did you try using Webflux? flux can have many subscribers and all the subscribers will get instant data

Comment: @EeshwarAnkathi i think it can't work with only Webflux beacuse how Webflux know when data is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

- Publish your updated data to some channel
- Your clients should subscribe to that channel to get updated feed in real-time.

**Tools**

- Use in-house setup for RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, Kafka or other open-source tools and implement WebSocket (For Front end applications)
- Use commercial service like Google Cloud PubSub
- Readymade and fully packaged solution with supported SDK for backend and frontend, https://www.pubnub.com/.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use either of

- Spring Integration
- Web Sockets
- JMS

Spring Integration is an implementation of Enterprise Integration Patterns and is ideal for asynchronous processing data at realtime.

However, looking at your scope, it is only about publisher-subscriber pattern. Hence can be solved with JMS.
With JMS the subscribers/consumers can register/de-register dynamically. Also it provides ways to have fall-backs and tracking.